# iis express consumes 90% of cpu while the server is idle

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iis, signalr

I'm working on a MVC .Net project that uses SignalR as a bi-directional communication between he client and server side.

Lately I've noticed that my CPU is getting overloaded quite quickly when I start the server (from visual studio). I looked around in task manager and seen that `iisexpress.exe` is consuming almost 90% of my CPU, and if I pause the project it shows that the server is idle and yet it's consuming all of my CPU.

I also tried to run the project on a much stronger PC, but the results were the same.

I read about this issue and saw this is a known issue which can be solved by turning off the `browser link` option, so I tried that, but not only that it didn't drop my CPU usage back to normal, but it also killed my connection between the server and the client side. Apparently this option is based on the SignalR technology, so by turning that option off I basically kill the communication between them.

I have three questions about it:

1. How can I solve this issue? turning off `browser link` doesn't work.
2. Will this problem persist even after I'll publish the project to the server? meaning it will run directly on the IIS server without VS in the background?
3. Is it not recommended to use SignalR on large HTML pages?

I would really appreciate your help!

Comment: Are you able to test the application against IIS (not the express version)? If so, does it behave the same way?

Comment: @MikeHofer no, I haven't tried to run it on IIS (non-express). I will have access to the project server only in a few days from now so I can't test it there yet. Can I set VS to run my project on this version instead of the express version?

Comment: You should be able to test IIS locally on your machine. Control Panel -> Programs and Features -> Turn Windows features on or off. Then check the option for Internet Information Services. Expand the node for World Wide Web Services. Expand the section for Application Development Features, and check everything (just to be on the safe side). Restart your machine. You should be able to test locally on IIS running on your machine.

Comment: @MikeHofer thanks, I'm giving it a try...

Comment: @MikeHofer, I've tried to change the project web properties to run on local IIS, and I'm getting this error:
`Configuring Web http://... for ASP.NET 4.5 failed. You must manually configure this site for ASP.NET 4.5 in order for the site to run correctly. ASP.NET 4.0 has not been registered on the WebServer. You need to manually configure your Web server for ASP.NET in order for your site to run correctly.`

I've looked up in `Application Development Features` I don't have those 2 version (4.0 & 4.5) in there...

Comment: See this page for the fix: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2014/11/11/dialog-box-may-be-displayed-to-users-when-opening-projects-in-microsoft-visual-studio-after-installation-of-microsoft-net-framework-4-6.aspx

Comment: @Mike Hofer thanks for your help. so far I moved the db to something local (instead of the project MDF file), I needed to change this so I can move from iisexpress, but after I made this change, it seems like the problem is gone. I didn't move from iisexpress yet but I will update if this problem recurs. Again, thanks for your help!